# How to mock a module method that is included in a contrroller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm using recaptcha and I need to mock the verify_captcha method.
This method is included in the controller by recaptcha gem:

```
ActiveSupport.on_load(:action_controller) do
  include Recaptcha::Adapters::ControllerMethods
end
```

How can I mock verify_captcha method (that is inside Recaptcha::Adapters::ControllerMethods) ?

I'm using:

```
allow_any_instance_of(ApplicationController).to receive(:verify_recaptcha).and_return(true)
```

But rubocop says that is not the best way.

Comment: https://github.com/ambethia/recaptcha#testing

Answer (score 0):

Rubocop doesn't like `allow_any_instance_of`, and frankly, neither does RSpec.

But, stubbing out ApplicationController can be a bit tricky.

You should be able to use a [`spy`](https://rspec.info/features/3-12/rspec-mocks/basics/spies/).

```rb
app_controller_spy = spy("ApplicationController")

expect(app_controller_spy).to receive(:verify_recaptcha).and_return(true)
```

Better yet, don't test other people code, only your own. The gem has its own code coverage and you trusted it enough to put it in your project.

All you need to test is that `ActionController` has `Recaptcha::Adapters::ControllerMethods` included to affirm that you've done your work.